# Противоположность понятий "чудовище" / "монстр"

Tags: одним-словом

Как назвать человека который поражает своими особыми свойствами/качествами одним словом?

Если в негативном ключе, то можно использовать слова **монстр**/**чудовище**.

А если хочется в положительном смысле?

(есть вариант **герой**, но это более узкое по значению слово, как мне кажется)

Comment: Гений, звезда, супергерой :)

Comment: В последнее время монстр/зверь часто используются в положительном смысле. Может слегка иронично, но с восхищением.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please provide a phrase in Russian with a blank to fill with the word you're looking for? Thanks!

Comment: "Какая глыба, а? Какой матерый человечище!" (c)

Comment: Молодец, красавчик

Comment: идеал. ангел. ну что - противоположное чудовищу ? :> сами не знаете ? (на каком бы языке не говорили...)

Answer (score 2):

- Герой - чудовище. Чудовище совершает подлые и злые поступки, герой - добрые и благородные.
- Спаситель - чудовище. Чудовище вершит зло, спаситель устраняет это зло или его последствия.
- Святой - чудовище. Чудовище совершает много подлых и злых деяний, святой - ни одного.
- Человек - чудовище. Чудовище своими действиями растрачивает остатки человечности, человек остается человечным.